Inverse spacial fourier transform of Retarded Green's Function
I'm currently taking a course on many-body QFT and came across this integral when computing the full-Born approximation for a random external potential. The book is "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics" by Henrik Bruus and Karsten Flensberg. This is the paragraph before the equation which mentions which approximations we should make:
We close this section by remarking three properties summarized in Fig. 12.5 related to the retarded Green’s function $G_R^{1BA}(\omega) = G^{1BA}(\omega + i \eta)$. First, it is seen by Fourier transforming to the time domain that $G_R^{1BA}(t)$ decays exponentially in time with $\tau_k$ as the typical time scale,
$$
G_R^{1BA}(t) \equiv \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{e^{-i(\omega + i \eta) t}}{\omega - \xi_k + i / 2 \tau_k} = -i \theta(t) e^{-i \xi_k t} e^{-t / 2 \tau_k}
$$
Second, exploiting that $\omega, \tau^{-1}_k \ll \epsilon_F$, it is seen by Fourier transforming back to real space that $G_R^{1BA} (r, \omega)$ decays exponentially in space with $l_k \equiv v_F \tau_k$ as the typical length scale.
$$G_R^{1BA} (r, \omega) \equiv \int \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}}}{\omega - \xi_k + i / 2 \tau_k} 
= \frac{\pi d(\epsilon_F)}{k_F | \mathbf{r} |} e^{i k_F | \mathbf{r} |} e^{- | \mathbf{r} | / 2 l_k}$$
My question is how did the authors calculate the second integral?

It seems that you didn't cite the paragraph you wanted to. Secondly, you didn't ask any question.

Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed the question now.
